# Кликабельность кнопок в новом окне

Tags: javascript, html, css

При открытии нового окна span становится не кликабельным.
Код открытия нового окна.

```
<a onclick="_open('http://test.ru',850,550);" href="javascript://">добавить в корзину</a>

function _open( url, width, height ) {
    window.open( url, '', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',left=' + ((window.innerWidth - width)/2) + ',top=' + ((window.innerHeight - height)/2) );
}
```

код span, которые должны быть кликабельными:

```
<div class="number">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="text" value="1" size="5"/>
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.minus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.plus').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

При прямом заходе на test.ru всё нормально и при клике на span значения в input меняется, но при открытии нового окна span становятся не кликабельны. В чём может быть проблема?